# merge two arrays, while maintaining the numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to merge two arrays together.  both have numeric keys and are unique.  when i use array_merge, it re-indexes starting at 0.

so lets say i have

```
[2] = abc
[5] = cde
```

and i have

```
[32] = fge
[13] = def
```

i want to merge these two together maintaining the unique keys.

below is the explaination on the current merge behavior.. any way around this?

"If all of the arrays contain only numeric keys, the resulting array is given incrementing keys starting from zero."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using the `+` operator.

```
$one = array(2 => 'abc', 5 => 'cde');
$two = array(32 => 'fge', 13 => 'def');
$three = $one + $two;
```

`$three` should now look like this:

```
[2] = abc
[5] = cde
[32] = fge
[13] = def
```

Answer (score 7):

if you want to merge arrays with numeric keys, keep the keys and override items from first array by items from second one:

```
$a = array(0 => "a", 1 => "b"); 
$b = array(1 => "c", 5 => "d"); 
var_dump(array_diff_key($a, $b) + $b);
```

will produce:

```
array(3) {   
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [array union operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) `+`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array(2 => 'abc', 5 => 'cde') + array(32 => 'fge', 13 => 'def');
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();
$arrmerge = array();
array_push($arr, $arr1, $arr2);
```

$arr1 and $arr2 will be merge and stored in $arrmerge. You can access it by foreach.

Hope it works!

Comment: Actually no, this would create a multidimensional array `array($arr1, $arr2)`.